# gawk: Summing floats formatted with comma separator

Tags: awk, locale, gawk

I'm trying to sum floats which use the comma as separator, and gawk does integer calculations. Here's the script:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=";"
  OFS=";"
  CONVFMT = "%2.2f"
}
{ 
  print $1
  print $2
  print $1+$2 
}
```

I'm using this data file:

```
4,3;5,7
```

and calling the script like this:

```
LC_ALL=fr_BE gawk -f test.awk < t.txt
```

I get this output:

```
4,3
5,7
9
```

I have the fr_BE locale set up, but the result is still incorrect. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is to use the `--use-lc-numeric` gawk option.

> --use-lc-numeric
>
> This forces gawk to use the locale's decimal point character when
>   parsing input data. Although the POSIX standard requires this
>   behavior, and gawk does so when --posix is in effect, the default is
>   to follow traditional behavior and use a period as the decimal point,
>   even in locales where the period is not the decimal point character.
>   This option overrides the default behavior, without the full draconian
>   strictness of the --posix option.

#### Example

Say we have this data file:

```
$ cat t.txt 
4,3;5,7
4,9;5,7
```

To ease in seeing the output, I changed this line in `test.awk`:

```
print "Total: "$1+$2
```

Now when you run it using the above mentioned switch:

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_BE gawk --use-lc-numeric -f test.awk < t.txt
4,3
5,7
Total: 10
4,9
5,7
Total: 10,60
```

#### References

- [gawk floating-point number localization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16832395/7552)
- [6.1.4 Conversion of Strings and Numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion.html#Conversion)

Comment: I think this solution will not work. `gawk` can not convert string `4,3` to float number.

Comment: @Gnouc do you think or know it? I tried it with gawk 3 an 4 and it seems to work..

Comment: I try with `gawk 3.1.8`, Ubuntu 12.04 and it does not work.

Comment: It does work with `gawk 4.0.1`, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Might not work with `LC_ALL=fr_BE`, though.  Try `LC_ALL=fr_BE.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `gawk` can not convert string `4,3` to a float number. You can fix it by replace `,` with `.`. For @glenn jackman input:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=";"
  OFS=";"
  CONVFMT = "%2.2f"
}
{
  gsub(",",".",$0)
  print $1
  print $2
  print $1+$2
}

$ LC_ALL=fr_BE gawk -f test.awk < file
4.3
5.7
10
4.9
5.7
10.6
```