# Converting awk printf string to decimal

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, top, numeric-data

**Task:**

stdout the load avg from top in a decimal form like (e.g 0.23)

**Details:**

I need to parse this script to Chef's inspec and check if its result is bigger/smaller than something, for example:

```
describe command("top -b -n  1  | awk  '/load average/ { sub(/,/,\".\",$10); printf \"%f\n\",$10}'") do
  its("stdout") { should eq 0.00 }    
end
```

This example returns ""

But now when I think about it, I could compare with a file in `/proc/loadavg`

**Progress**

Used this resource: [Grab the load average with top](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239952/grab-the-load-average-with-top)

With this command, I get a good representation of the output, but it's a string and I can't do any mathematical operations with it:

```
martin@martinv-pc:~$ top -b -n  1  | awk '/load average/ { printf "%s\n", $10}'
0,63,
```

But when I try to change the printf to decimal/float, I get an error:

```
martin@martinv-pc:~$ top -b -n  1  | awk '/load average/ { printf "%f\n", $10}'
0.000000
martin@martinv-pc:~$ top -b -n  1  | awk '/load average/ { printf "%d\n", $10}'
0
```

Can't echo, tried with cut, **bad idea** -- not working:

```
martin@martinv-pc:~$ top -b -n  1  | awk '/load average/ { printf "%s\n", $10}'|cut -c1-4
0,15
martin@martinv-pc:~$ top -b -n  1  | awk '/load average/ { printf "%s\n", $10}'|$((cut -c1-4))
-4: command not found
```

Another attempt:

```
martin@martinv-pc:~$ top -b -n  1  | awk '/load average/ BEGIN { printf "%.f\n", $10};'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near BEGIN
```

**Question:**

How can I convert the string value to decimal/float/integer ?

`ps -o user,rss` output:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps -o user,rss
USER       RSS
vagrant    736
vagrant   1080
```

Comment: I don't think you can rely on the load average always being in field #10 - it will vary depending on the machine's uptime (since the uptime string will go from H:M to something like `d days, H:M`)

Comment: Which load average, the 1 minute, 5 minute or 15 minute average?  Why are you parsing the output of `top`? Wouldn't `uptime` be better, or if your system supports it, one of the `sysctl` variables (`sysctl vm.loadavg` on OpenBSD).

Comment: I need all the all the load averages for 1,5,15 mins

Comment: @steeldriver What do you suggest then ?

Comment: OK, so what values do you need? You seem to be comparing  `its("stdout")` expecting a single value. Which one? And you really don't need `%f` if you remove the comma. But if you show us what output you want, we can give it to you.

Comment: @terdon In short I need a decimal value. The problem is that when I execute a bash script in inspec, things get wrong, results are not expected and probably my question is not properly asked

Comment: ps -o user,rss | awk -F\  '{q[$1]+=$2/1024/1024} END {for(a in q) printf "%20s %10.3f%1s\n",a,q[a]}' return memory usage, if I got you correct

Comment: @murloc I realize you need a decimal value, but you need to tell us which of the three numbers returned by `top` you are interested in.

Comment: If this is on Linux, you can just read the file `/proc/loadavg`.

Comment: @twalberg yeah I am trying that as well

Comment: @terdon I need all the values from the workload avg but one by one a script for each, the problem is that this is not the question... the question should be different and should be on a DevOps, ruby related site. The edit I've made is the actual problem I have. Sorry, I've asked a bad question ..

Comment: @HosseinVatani It doesn't work on CentOS6

Comment: I have not centos6 now but I don't think so, please provide the result of ps -o user,rss.

Comment: @HosseinVatani made an edit about it

Comment: thanks, and what about the result? please put the result as a comment in here.

Comment: I've added the result in the question itself, look above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Task:**

> sdout the load avg from top in a decimal form like(e.g 0.23)

**Solution:**

```
top -b -n  1  | perl -lane 'print "$1.$2" if /load average: (\d+)[,.](\d+)/'
```

**Notes:**

This retrieves the 1m load average. It looks like this is what you want, but you should state it clearly. If needed, the code can be easily modified to retrieve the load averages over 5 minutes or 15 minutes, or even all three.

As pointed out by [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon), `uptime` might be a better starting point than `top` in this case.

After the first two lines, you *obscurely* describe what you want to do with the result. Subsequent steps you want to take should be the subject of new questions.

In Perl, numbers are auto-casted to strings and vice-versa. Any numerical operation can be performed on a string representing a number. e.g. `print "$1.$2"+11.11`

---

**Question 2:**

This part is about the second question, which is *totally unrelated* to the first one.
**I urge the OP to post this question separately**.

> How Can I convert the string value to decimal/float/integer ?

Better written as: Performing numeric comparisons on strings with [Chef](https://www.chef.io)'s [InSpec](https://www.inspec.io).

**Solution:**

Convert the string to a numeric format, with either `to_i` or `to_f`.

**Example:**

```
describe command("echo 1.00") do
    its("stdout.to_f") { should be < 1.03 }
end
```

**Explanation:**

Very reasonably, stdout is treated as a string. Also very reasonably, *numeric* comparisons require the two numbers to be...numbers. Luckily, conversion can be done with the handy Ruby string methods: `to_i`, `to_f`, `to_r` and `to_c`.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't go to Perl by rather Ruby and inspec, the EDIT I've maid is crucial and it's the issue I am experiencing. I need all the load avg scores { 1, 5, 15} if I have one of them, the rest are clear. As you've said the problem is in the subsequent question, meaning that I've asked a bad question

Comment: @murloc Actually, you posed a perfectly valid question and it has been answered: therefore, I think you should accept one of the proposed solutions that satisfy the requirements. Then, you are invited to ask a new question about the next step, providing all the needed details.

Comment: Yeah it works, thank you but how can I do this for the other variables ( for 1 and 5 mins)

Comment: @murloc You could create three InSpec controls, one for each of the three values, with a regex similar to `(\d+)[,.](\d+)\D+(\d+)[,.](\d+)\D+(\d+)[,.](\d+)`. If you need help with regular expressions and capturing groups, that would be a third question.

Answer (score 2):

From [gawk: Summing floats formatted with comma separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121000/gawk-summing-floats-formatted-with-comma-separator) :

The answer is to use the `--use-lc-numeric` gawk option.

> --use-lc-numeric
>
> This forces gawk to use the locale's decimal point character when
>   parsing input data. Although the POSIX standard requires this
>   behavior, and gawk does so when --posix is in effect, the default is
>   to follow traditional behavior and use a period as the decimal point,
>   even in locales where the period is not the decimal point character.
>   This option overrides the default behavior, without the full draconian
>   strictness of the --posix option.

In your case, this command should work:

`top -b -n  1  | awk --use-lc-numeric '/load average/ { printf "%f\n", $10}'`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work,  the problem is that I am parsing this command to chef's inspec and it's returning ""

Comment: So if you need the output using dot instead of colon use the option 1 of @terdon answer

Comment: maybe I should try another approach

Comment: @murloc you might want to explain what is doing the "arithmetical operations". Is it awk itself? Some other program? The `printf` shouldn't be relevant in most cases if the problem is the comma.

Comment: I will do an edit explaining

Answer (score 2):

You are presumably using a locale that has `,` as the decimal separator. You can try any of these approaches:

1. Use the C locale for `top`:

   ```
   LC_ALL=C top -b -n  1  | awk  '/load average/ { printf "%f\n",$10}'
   ```

   That not only addresses the period versus comma issue but would also avoid problems with text like `load average` translated into the user's language.
2. Replace the comma with a dot:

   ```
   top -b -n  1  | awk  '/load average/ { sub(/,/,".",$10); printf "%f\n",$10}'
   ```
3. With GNU `awk`, use the `--use-lc-numeric` flag [suggested by @Leo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458323/22222) or use `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk`.
4. Or use a POSIX compliant `awk` implementation like [the One True awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk)  which should parse and print numbers according to locale rules by default.

Note that a more portable command to get the load average is `uptime`.

Comment: I've made an edit explaining my problem, these are all working but not for my case

Comment: I think I will try to make something with this uptime function, should be easier

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the field extracted is using the comma as the decimal separator and awk expects floats to use a dot.

This reproduces your problem:

```
$ LC_ALL=de_DE top -bn 1 | awk 'NR==1'
top - 08:37:07 up 1 day, 10:22,  5 users,  load average: 0,17, 0,24, 0,26
```

As you can see, the numbers use a comma as decimal separator. You need something similar to:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US top -bn 1 | awk 'NR==1'
top - 08:38:28 up 1 day, 10:23,  5 users,  load average: 0.56, 0.34, 0.30
```

But that will depend of which locales have been installed (check with `locale -a`) on your system. A `C` locale is always available.

```
$ LC_ALL=C top -bn 1 | awk 'NR==1'
top - 08:40:35 up 1 day, 10:25,  5 users,  load average: 0.50, 0.39, 0.31
```

But using top to only extract the first line is overkill. Better use uptime:

```
$ LC_ALL=C uptime
08:42:08 up 1 day, 10:27,  5 users,  load average: 0.35, 0.37, 0.31
```

But even better, read the `/proc/loadavg` file

```
$ cat /proc/loadavg 
0.29 0.34 0.30 1/468 15084
```

Which, by the way, is not affected by the locale. The first number is the 1 minute load average, just select it and print in any format:

```
$ awk '{printf( "%s\n %f\n %d\n", $1, $1, $1 )}' /proc/loadavg
0.35
0.350000
0
```

For the 1, 5 and 15 minutes load average use:

```
$ awk '{printf( "%7.3f %7.3f %5.2f\n", $1, $2, $3 )}' /proc/loadavg
 0.150   0.340  0.33
```

Comment: Note that `/proc/loadavg` is Linux-specific.